# in python, write a function called wordendwithS() , to count the number of words ending with 's' from the TEXT FILE "file.txt"

Tags: python-2.7

I have already tried

```
def wordendwithS():

    f=open("file.txt",'r')

    a=f.readlines() 
    c=0
    for i in a: 

        if i.endswith('s'):
            c=c+1
```

I dont know what to do please help

What is wrong in this?

Comment: You're not returning `c`.

Comment: And to add to what @Eli said, you're not checking words, you're checking lines since `i` is simply each line of the text file.

Comment: Is there any error message? Are you getting wrong output? Doesn't your code work?

Comment: You can pretty simply do `c = 0` `with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:` `for l in f:` `for i in l.split():` `if i.endswith('s'): c += 1`

Comment: You said you don't know what to do. Where exactly is your problem? You get an unexpected error? An unexpected outcome? You need to desrcribe your problem more precise. This is not a site which solves your homeworks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems with your code. The first is that you're not returning the count `c` which means that your function is doing nothing. Additionally, you are checking if a line ends with `'s'` instead of if a word ends with `'s'`. Third, you are not closing your file. You can do this to fix all three of these problems

```
def wordendwithS():
    c = 0 
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: 
        for l in f: 
            for i in l.split(): 
                if i.endswith('s'): 
                    c += 1
    return c
```

`with` is a content manager which autocloses the file after you're done using it.